# Half cell boundary condition

Tags: numerical-methods, boundary

I have a problem, I am solving set of equations via this numerical scheme

uN(i+1/2) = uP(i+1/2) + dt*f( uP((i+1/2), uP(i-1/2), P(i), P(i-1) )

uN ... velocity in New time step

uP ... velocity in Previous time step

P  ... pressure in previous time step

i  ... number of cell boundary

i+1/2 ... number of cell center

[image]

P0 is given as left boundary condition, enter code here, I dont know how to determine u1/2, original text proposes using half cell. But I am not sure how exactly formulate the equation for half cell.

Comment: Do you know how to do it in paper? It's the best point to start. Then write down an algorithm, show us and we'll help.

Comment: Actually not really, that is where I have problem, I am trying to solve set of equations in this paper:
https://dspace.mit.edu/bitstream/handle/1721.1/89626/17819264.pdf?sequence=1

on page 12: eqs 10, 11, 12
on page 13: eqs 13, 14, 15 ... num schemes
on page 14 there is paragraph about handling the boundary conditions and it does not make much sence to me

Comment: What you should do is break the process down into small tasks. Then you should get there. But for us to help you, you should give us some code. ok?